# Why does the code continue to print elements, when the list it's printing from only has 1 element in it?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Why does the code continue to print elements, when the list it's printing from only has 1 element in it?

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

---

```
package com.mkyong.seo;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

    File file = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");

    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                             .newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {

        printNote(doc.getChildNodes());

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

  }

  private static void printNote(NodeList nodeList) {

    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

    Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

    // make sure it's element node.
    if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        // get node name and value
        System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
        System.out.println("Node Value =" + tempNode.getTextContent());

        if (tempNode.hasAttributes()) {

            // get attributes names and values
            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                System.out.println("attr name : " + node.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("attr value : " + node.getNodeValue());

            }

        }

        if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {

            // loop again if has child nodes
            printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());

        }

        System.out.println("Node Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");

    }

    }

  }

}
```

---

OUTPUT:--

```
Root element :company

Node Name =company [OPEN]
Node Value =

        yong
        mook kim
        mkyong
        100000


        low
        yin fong
        fong fong
        200000



Node Name =staff [OPEN]
Node Value =
        yong
        mook kim
        mkyong
        100000

attr name : id
attr value : 1001

Node Name =firstname [OPEN]
Node Value =yong
Node Name =firstname [CLOSE]

Node Name =lastname [OPEN]
Node Value =mook kim
Node Name =lastname [CLOSE]

Node Name =nickname [OPEN]
Node Value =mkyong
Node Name =nickname [CLOSE]

Node Name =salary [OPEN]
Node Value =100000
Node Name =salary [CLOSE]
Node Name =staff [CLOSE]

Node Name =staff [OPEN]
Node Value =
        low
        yin fong
        fong fong
        200000

attr name : id
attr value : 2001

Node Name =firstname [OPEN]
Node Value =low
Node Name =firstname [CLOSE]

Node Name =lastname [OPEN]
Node Value =yin fong
Node Name =lastname [CLOSE]

Node Name =nickname [OPEN]
Node Value =fong fong
Node Name =nickname [CLOSE]

Node Name =salary [OPEN]
Node Value =200000
Node Name =salary [CLOSE]
Node Name =staff [CLOSE]
Node Name =company [CLOSE]
```

According to me the output shouldn't have passed beyond:-

```
Node Name =firstname [OPEN]
Node Value =low
Node Name =firstname [CLOSE]
```

1st time.

Please help

Comment: "/Users/mkyong/staff.xml", my dear sir. Do you have it?

Comment: yes I do have the xml with me. I have posted it

Comment: I have asked it sir. I am not able to get why I am getting the output after the first name because the nodelist at that point of time holds only 1 element which is a text node.

Comment: It pays to repeat the question in the first line of the body of a post.  A lot of people will open 10 posts they think they can help with, in ten new tabs of the browser.  After they return to the tab, the title becomes 'invisible' to them, as they concentrate on the body of the post.  It is also extremely handy to add a '?' to questions.  Sometimes I do a 'find' on '?' and if there is none in a post, I'll vote to close.  @M21B8  I've added another vote to reopen..

Answer (score 1):

You're browsing through the XML as if it were a tree, going along each branch at a time. The reason the list you're printing only has 1 element in it, is because in that branch, you are at element firstname, which has 1 child, a text node saying 'low' when that finishes executing, you step back to the previous branch, and move on to that elements next child (lastname). This may become a little bit clearer if you add something to show which level of branch you are on (to show how deep you are down the tree), the code is the same, but i have added an integer 'depth' which is printed out to show the depth in the tree, which should help it become clearer how the recursion is working..

e.g.

```
package com.mkyong.seo;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

File file = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");

DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                         .newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {

    printNote(doc.getChildNodes(), 1);

}

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

}

private static void printNote(NodeList nodeList, int depth) {

for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

// make sure it's element node.
if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

    // get node name and value
    System.out.println(depth + "\nNode Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
    System.out.println(depth + "Node Value =" + tempNode.getTextContent());

    if (tempNode.hasAttributes()) {

        // get attributes names and values
        NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
            System.out.println("attr name : " + node.getNodeName());
            System.out.println("attr value : " + node.getNodeValue());

        }

    }

    if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {

        // loop again if has child nodes
        printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes(), depth+1);

    }

    System.out.println(depth + "Node Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");

}

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to print all children of the document root node, recursively. You're getting exactly what you asked for. Why do you think it should have stopped?